# AWS KMI - force key rotation if compromised

Tags: security, amazon-web-services

How do I force AWS KMI to rotate a key after a compromise? It seems I can instruct AWS to automatically rotate keys once a year. But on demand, if compromised - doesn't seem possible. Specifically, the PCI-DSS requirements:

3.6.5

a) Do cryptographic key procedures include retirement or replacement (for example, archiving, destruction, and/or revocation) of cryptographic keys when the integrity of the key has been weakened (for example, departure of an employee with knowledge of a clear-text key)?

b) Do cryptographic key procedures include replacement of known or suspected compromised keys?

Answer (score 0):

(When you say KMI, I guess you mean AWS KMS.)

This is a valid question. The way to rotate keys manually is to create a new key and change the alias from the old key to the new one. Unfortunately, most AWS resources use the key id, so you have to assess which one is still using the old one.

If you use Infrastructure as Code tools such as Terraform or Pulumi, you just need to taint the KMS resource, so it will be recreated with a new ID and if you did everything right, e.g. used the alias-based data queries in Terraform, you just need to run the pipelines for those resources, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I force AWS KMI to rotate a key after a compromise?

**Key rotation doesn't mitigate compromised key data.**

*Key rotation* is a mechanism to prevent encrypting too many chunks of data (there is a math about relation between amount of encrypted data and probability of key revelation)

Basically the key rotation creates a new version of the key for new encryptions, but KMS will allow decrypting any ciphertext encrypted with the older key version.

See:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/rotate-keys.html#rotate-keys-manually

> Unfortunately, most AWS resources use the key id, so you have to assess which one is still using the old one.

When using manual key rotation, the application needs to know which key is the current one (e.g. using an alias), but the ciphertext needs a reference to the key id/arn to decrypt.

> But on demand, if compromised - doesn't seem possible.

By default the KMS key doesn't leave the hardware. There is no way the KMS key itself is compromised, so maybe an automatic rotation is feasible having all the advantages (keeping the same ARN/ID/alias)

However - the KMS is meant for [envelope encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/concepts.html#envelope-encryption), KMS is used to encrypt the random data-key or a service-specific key, which can be leaked theoretically. Then you need to create policies to manage this risk